# Find a cubic interpolating polnomial that fits the data points using Vandermonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> The data points are (-1,0), (1,2), (3,20), (5,102)

I'm not sure how to set up the matrix for this question. I understand the matrix equation is $Va=y$ where $V$ is a Vandermonde matrix and I have to solve for $a$. Would $y$ be $[0, 2, 20, 102]$? And how would I set up the matrix? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We are given the data points:

$$(x, y) = (-1,0), (1,2), (3,20), (5,102)$$

We are looking for the cubic:

$$y(x) = a + bx + c x^2 + dx^3$$

To find the [*cubic interpolating polynomial*](http://www.cs.ntou.edu.tw/indexs/files/fslin/SC/SctcCh2st.pdf) (see $2.1$), we set up and solve using the Vandermonde (write it in matrix form to see it if it is not clear) matrix:

$$a + b(-1) + c(-1)^2 + d (-1)^3 = 0 \\
a + b(~1) + c(~1)^2 + d(~1)^3 = 2 \\
a + b(~3) + c(~3)^2 + d(~3)^3 = 20 \\
a + b(~5) + c(~5)^2 + d(~5)^3 = 102 $$

This yields:

$$a = 2, b = 0, c = -1, d = 1$$

Answer (score 0):

Let the polynomial be $f = a_3x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$ and $(x_0, y_0),(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3)$ are the data points, so you are searching $a_3, a_2, a_1, a_0$. Then you have to solve the system :

$$
\left| 
  \begin{array}{l}
    a_3x_0^3 + a_2x_0^2 + a_1x_0 + a_1 = y_0 \\
    a_3x_1^3 + a_2x_1^2 + a_1x_1 + a_1 = y_1 \\
    a_3x_2^3 + a_2x_2^2 + a_1x_2 + a_1 = y_2 \\
    a_3x_3^3 + a_2x_3^2 + a_1x_3 + a_1 = y_3
  \end{array} \right.
$$
Which is the equation with the Vandermonde matrix that you want:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_0^3 & x_0^2 & x_0 & 1 \\
x_1^3 & x_1^2 & x_1 & 1 \\
x_2^3 & x_2^2 & x_2 & 1 \\
x_3^3 & x_3^2 & x_3 & 1
\end{pmatrix} &
\begin{pmatrix}
a_3\\
a_2 \\
a_1 \\
a_0
\end{pmatrix} & = &
\begin{pmatrix}
y_0\\
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
y_3
\end{pmatrix}
\end{matrix}
$$

Solutions can be found with the Cramer's rule:

$$
\begin{matrix}
a_3 & = & 
\frac{\begin{vmatrix}
y_0 & x_0^2 & x_0 & 1 \\
y_1 & x_1^2 & x_1 & 1 \\
y_2 & x_2^2 & x_2 & 1 \\
y_3 & x_3^2 & x_3 & 1
\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
x_0^3 & x_0^2 & x_0 & 1 \\
x_1^3 & x_1^2 & x_1 & 1 \\
x_2^3 & x_2^2 & x_2 & 1 \\
x_3^3 & x_3^2 & x_3 & 1
\end{vmatrix}}
\end{matrix}
$$

and similarly for $a_2, a_1, a_0$.